# Angular interceptor return value outside observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, indexeddb

I am using Angular 6 and I am coding an API which uses access tokens as an authentication mechanism. Basically I set the Authorization Bearer token on the headers using an interceptor and then send it as a request.

At first I was storing the access token in local storage and getting it from there to set it as the authorization bearer. However, i am now using IndexDB since I will begin working with service workers and PWA. So I am now using an asynchronous library `@ngx-pwa/local-storage` which wraps everything in observables.

Now I don't know how to return the value outside of the function because I need to get the token in a synchronomous manner before sending the next interception handle. What is the best way of doing this?

```
this.localStorage.getItem('access_token').subscribe(token => {
  const cloned = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
  });
  return next.handle(cloned); // does not work
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `this.localStorage.getItem('access_token')` gets the key from IndexDB and returns an Observable. The only thing you need to do is wait until the `getItem` completes and then continue with `next.handle(cloned)` which means you can use for example the `concatMap` operator:

```
return this.localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  .pipe(
    concatMap(token => {
      const cloned = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      });
      return next.handle(cloned);
    })
  );
```

The above code will go to your interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the async/await keywords:

```
async someFunction(...){
    ....
    const token = await this.localStorage.getItem('access_token').toPromise();
    const cloned = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this._auth.ACCESS_TOKEN)
    });
    // Do whatever you need to with 'cloned'
}
```

The await keyword will force execution of the function to wait until the `localStorage.getItem` call has completed.